# MCP9600 with Raspberry

Tags: python, i2c

I'm getting mad with MCP9600 from *Adafruit*.
I'm using Raspberry and I connected to it only the MCP.
After to download the with pip the library, I try to run the example by *Adafruit*:

```py
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mcp9600

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=100000)
mcp = adafruit_mcp9600.MCP9600(i2c)

while True:
    print((mcp.ambient_temperature, mcp.temperature, mcp.delta_temperature))
    time.sleep(1)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/adafruit_bus_device/i2c_device.py", line 169, in __probe_for_device
  self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.device_address, result)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/busio.py", line 74, in readfrom_into
  return self._i2c.readfrom_into(address, buffer, stop=stop)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/i2c.py", line 44, in readfrom_into
  readin = self._i2c_bus.read_bytes(address, end-start)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 155, in read_bytes
  return self._device.read(number)
OSError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I would be really happy if some can help me.

Comment: I don't know this hardware but it looks like it needs [a driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_MCP9600): you've installed that OK, and there are no error messages from it in dmesg or /var/log/messages?

Comment: It might also be worth asking Adafruit directly if you haven't already.